# Cookie is not getting setted up in my Spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


         response.addCookie(new Cookie("COOKIENAME", "The cookie's value"));
         //...
         request.getSession().setAttribute("userName", userName);

         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("main-decorator");        
         model.getModel().put("versionInfo", getVersionInfo());
         //...
         return model;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the path on the cookie to "/"?

Comment: Hey tjg 184, Thanks for your quick response. I haven't, but I'll do it right away. I'll keep you posted

Comment: I tried and nothing... Cookie coo= new Cookie("COOKIENAME", "The cookie's value");
  coo.setPath("/");
  response.addCookie(coo);

Comment: How are you validating the cookies are not being set?

Comment: // Retrieve and set the File ID cookie
Cookie wareIdCookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "name here");

if (wareIdCookie != null) {
    warehouseID = wareIdCookie.getValue();
}

Comment: also in the JSP I have some java code retrieving and showing the coockies have being setted

Comment: //Getting the coockie 
         Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

Comment: Still thinking here, but verify the names of the cookies match here.  You might try printing out all cookies here.

Comment: Ok.Thanks..If something come to your mind feel free to tell me. I'm working also with a couple more of controllers ..I'm using the same approach and they are working fine. I don't understand why this one NOT